# How to access "default" property of attribute in Gutenberg

Tags: block-editor

In a Gutenberg block I try to read the value of an attribute's *default* property, so that I can find out in the transformation routine (to another block type) if any give attribute still has the default value.

With `this.props.attributes` I only see the *values* of attributes, but I need their "meta data".

One sample declaration in **registerBlockType** would look like:

```
attributes: {
    amount: {
      type: 'integer',
      default: 1
    },
// ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out that I can simply define a variable when I register the block

```
var myBlock = registerBlockType( ... )
```

and then inside the anonymous function for "transform" I can access the attributes as

```
myBlock.attributes
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get it from the `wp.data` object.

For example, if you registered the block `my-block`:

```
registerBlockType('create-block/my-block', {
  attributes: {
    amount: {
      type: 'integer',
      default: 1
    },
    // ...
  }
  // ...
});
```

you can get the default value this way:

```
const attributeSettings = wp.data.select('core/blocks').getBlockType('create-block/my-block').attributes;
const defaultAmount = attributeSettings.amount.default;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a direct way to inspect an attributes default value but one way would you can indirectly achieve this is to store the default value in a variable.

You could then reference it from inside the attribute object and from the `edit` and `save` functions.

e.g. (untested)

```
const amountDefault = 1;

registerBlockType( 'test/myblock', {
    title: __( 'Test Block' ),
    attributes: {
        amount: {
            type: 'integer',
            default: amountDefault 
        }
    },
    edit: function( props ) {
        const { attributes: { amount } } = props;

        return (
            <div className={ props.className }>
                <h3>Editor</h3>
                The default amount is: {amountDefault}
                The actual amount is: {amount}
            </div>
        );
    },
    save: function( props ) {
        const { attributes: { amount } } = props;
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>Editor</h3>
                The default amount is: {amountDefault}
                The actual amount is: {amount}
            </div>
        );
    }
} );
```

This isn't ideal but should work as expected.

Comment: That sounds like a good solution, as there doesn't seem to be a way how to access it directly.

Comment: @dgwyer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54567380/gutenberg-dynamic-block-show-saved-data-in-the-editor do you have any idea about this ?